# How can a page be refreshed every 5 secconds only when tab/window has focus?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a iframe that I would like to refresh every 5 seconds, but only if the window or tab is active.

I was doing this with META Refresh, but I cant figure out a way to make this conditional to the page being active, so I have tried javascript, but without success.  This is what I have tried, but it is not working:

```
<SCRIPT>
  $(window).focus(function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
       window.location.reload(1);
        }, 5000);
    });
 <SCRIPT>
```

Am I headed in the right direction, or is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Looks like I forgot to call jquery in the iframe.  It is working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the [page visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) and check every 5 seconds the visibility state of your page: if it's not `hidden` then refresh the page

```
$(function() {
   window.setInterval(function() {
      if (!document.hidden) {
         window.location.reload(1);
      }
   }, 5000)
});
```

where `hidden` here means

> the page content is not visible to the user. In practice this means
>   that the document is either a background tab or part of a minimized
>   window, or the OS screen lock is active.

Comment: Just a small point. `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` is not needed since page is getting refreshed and code will get called again.

Comment: @Vishwanath if the page is not visibile you need to use instead setInterval, otherwise the check runs just once and the page doesn't reload when it is focused again